# OleDb paramater syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, parameters

When adding a parameter to an OLEDB command, is there a need to use 'new'. Both of the following work. Is one preferable or are they doing the same thing?

```
command.Parameters.Add(new OleDbParameter("name", OleDbType.VarChar)); 
command.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar);
```

Comment: There is no difference in how both the approach works. It for your convenience of what you want to use. If you have a separate method of creating parameters then you use the first approach else use the second approach

Comment: You can look at the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/OleDb/OleDbParameterCollection.cs,68 Notice how the method returns the parameter just created. This allows this syntax _command.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "YourValue";_

Comment: @Steve Im bookmarking that website, nice comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `Add(string, OleDbType)` overload calls the `Add(OleDbParameter)` overload. That means they do the same thing under the hood.

```
public OleDbParameter Add(string parameterName, OleDbType oleDbType)
{
     return Add(new OleDbParameter(parameterName, oleDbType));
}
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/fx/src/data/System/Data/OleDb/OleDbParameterCollection.cs,78

As Steve commented, most common way to use it (as far as I see) like;

```
command.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = "YourValue";
```

or if you know (of specify) your db column size (let's assume it is `varchar(10)`), you can add an integer as a third parameter like calling the [Add(parameterName, oleDbType, size) overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparametercollection.add?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Data_OleDb_OleDbType_System_Int32_);

```
command.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = "YourValue";
```

Comment: Thanks, I have multiple rows to add, so my intention is to declare the parameter then add the value in a subsequent loop with `command.Parameters["name"].Value = "value"` . I'm still unsure which is preferable in this instance.

Comment: @Bobney You can use `Parameters.AddRange` approach for this since this method takes `new OleDbParameter[]` as a parameter.

Comment: @SonerGönül Your last comment did misunderstand the OP intention. To reuse the parameter he/she should `var parameter = command.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar);` and inside the loop `parameter.Value = "whatever";`

Comment: @bradbury9 Oh, okay then. But in such a case, the parameter name, parameter value and OleDbType should exist in the structure of the object that you want to iterate.

Comment: Thanks, but all 3 methods (now including `var parameter = command.Parameters.Add("name", OleDbType.VarChar);`) seem to work. Is it just a case of convenience?

Comment: @Bobney Yes, if you don't assign the other parameters, they probably calculated based on parameter value. `AddWithValue` method has this problem for example. https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/